# other terms in equation to the same size as tfrac terms

Tags: equations, amsmath

How do I make other terms in equation to the same size as `tfrac` terms

```
\begin{equation}
X=\tfrac{2J^2}{4J^2+U^2/4}\sin^2\big(({\sqrt{4J^2+U^2/4}})t\big)
\end{equation}
```

looks like [image]

How do I adjust the size of the term inside `sin^2` to match with the `tfrac` terms ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    X=\tfrac{2J^2}{4J^2+U^2/4}
    \scriptstyle \sin^2\bigl(({\sqrt{4J^2+U^2/4}})t\bigr)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Or maybe you prefer this (bigger “sin”, amended spacing, resized parentheses…):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    X=\tfrac{2J^2}{4J^2+U^2\!/4}
    \sin^2\Bigl({\scriptstyle \bigl(\sqrt{4J^2+U^2\!/4}\bigr)\,t}\Bigr)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output (of the second code sample):

[image: Output of the second code sample]

---

**Addendum:**  @egreg criticism about the above parentheses being “awful” is too much for me to cope with: I *must* post some other attempt.  Perhaps this one could be regarded as acceptable:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    X=\tfrac{2J^2}{4J^2+U^2\!/4}
    \sin^2({\scriptstyle \sqrt{4J^2+U^2\!/4}\:\cdot\:t})
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This is the corresponding output:

[image: Output of the third code sample]

Comment: I can understand keeping the t at the end; but the size of the parentheses is awful.

Answer (score 5):

Why not :

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    X=\tfrac{2J^2}{4J^2+U^2\!/4}
    \sin^2\bigl({\scriptstyle t\,\sqrt{4J^2+U^2\!/4}}\bigr)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: If you highlight the lines of code and click on the `{}` "button" in the row above the editing window, the lines will be indented by four spaces and, importantly, will be pretty-printed by the site software.

Comment: I find this the best answer in the lot: moving the `t` avoids the need for additional parentheses and `\,` commands are tastefully applied. I'd suggest a `\,` more, just before the closing parenthesis, though. I also removed two lines: they're not needed for the example and might be confusing readers.

Comment: I like this, but I think you dropped a factor of 2?

Comment: @egreg: I too was tempted to move the “t” before the square root, but I decided to respect the OP’s preference for the ordering of the factors: I think (s)he deliberately put what is presumably the variable for *t* ime at the end, to keep the pattern of `\sin^2(\omega t)`.  Also, the two line you removed are mine! ;-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is optional, depending on the language used (it's recommended, though). The option `ascii` to `inputenc` is just wrong.

Comment: @egreg: My intent is the following: I know that I have written a pure, 7-bit-clean ASCII source, and I want to (a) make this clear to the reader, and (b) ensure that it is still pure, 7-bit-clean ASCII when the reader executes it (possibly after copying and pasting it).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti An inexperienced reader might think that the solution depends on this package option.

Comment: @egreg: OK, I’ll try to drop this habit (which I’ve just acquired, anyway), at least when posting here.  And I commit myself to do something for those parentheses, too…

Answer (score 4):

I think maybe you'll have too great a contrast betwwen different parts of your formula. I suggest using  the`\medmath` command, from `nccmath`, which reduces `displaymath` by about 80 %. Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
X & =\medmath{\frac{2J²}{4J²+U²/4}\sin²\Bigl(\Bigl({√{4J²+U²/4}}\Bigr)t\Bigr)}
\\
X & =\tfrac{2J²}{4J²+U²/4}\sin²{\scriptstyle\Bigl(\Bigl({√{4J²+U²/4}}\Bigr)t\Bigr)}
\\
X & =\frac{2J²}{4J²+U²/4}\sin²\Bigl(\Bigl({√{4J²+U²/4}}\Bigr)t\Bigr)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the inner parentheses for the `\sin` would look better if they "covered" the radical sign more completely; the relative size of the outer parens looks good, so if the inner parens get larger, the outer ones should also,

Comment: @barbara beeton: You're right. I wasn't in a (sentimental?) mood to tackle this problem, and I left this part of the O.P.'s code as is. I'll change that in a moment

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think that the problem is that you are "misusing" `\tfrac` because it is meant to fractions in in-line text. If instead you use `\frac` then the latex markup is simpler your problem goes away:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

    \textbf{With tfrac}
    \begin{equation}
        X=\tfrac{2J^2}{4J^2+U^2/4}\sin^2\big(({\sqrt{4J^2+U^2/4}})t\big)
    \end{equation}

    \textbf{With frac}
    \begin{equation}
        X=\frac{2J^2}{4J^2+U^2/4}\sin^2\big(({\sqrt{4J^2+U^2/4}})t\big)
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanx. there are long multiple equations involved and each terms are little lengthy, so if I use `\frac` it takes whole lot of space and it does not look nice. `\scriptstyle` with `\tfrac` solved the problem.